# Bandlimited reconstruction of sampled periodic functions.

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions, fast-fourier-transform

This has to do with the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling and reconstruction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) and the so-called [Whittaker–Shannon interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula).  I had previously asked [an ancillary question about this here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182750/can-i-get-an-independent-proof-of-a-closed-form-of-these-two-related-infinite-se) but this is about a specific nagging issue that seems to *"periodically"* crop up.

Let's begin with a periodic infinite sequence of real numbers, $a_n \in\mathbb{R}$, having period $N>0\in\mathbb{Z}$.  That is:

$$ a_{n+N}=a_n \qquad \forall \ n\in\mathbb{Z}. $$

So there are only $N$ unique values of $a_n$.

Imagine these discrete (but ordered) values as equally spaced on the real number line and being interpolated (between integer $n$) as

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n \, \operatorname{sinc}(x-n),$$

where

$$ \operatorname{sinc}(u) \triangleq \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u}  & \text{if } u \ne 0, \\\;1 & \text{if } u = 0. \end{cases} $$

Clearly $f(x)$ is periodic with the same period $N$:

$$ f(x+N) = f(x) \qquad \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}. $$

All terms are bandlimited to a maximum frequency of $\frac{1}{2}$, so the summation is bandlimited to the same bandlimit.  And, in any case, we have

$$ f(x) \Big|_{x = n} = a_n, $$

so the reconstruction works out exactly at the sampling instances.

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n \, \operatorname{sinc}(x-n) \\
     &= \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_{(n+mN)} \, \operatorname{sinc}\big(x - (n+mN)\big) \\
     &= \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \, \operatorname{sinc}\big(x - (n+mN)\big) \\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left(a_n \, \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}\big(x - (n+mN)\big)\right). \\
\end{align}$$

Substituting $u \triangleq x-n$ gives

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \, g(x-n), $$

where

$$ g(u) =  \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(u-mN). $$

Clearly the continuous (and real) $g(u)$ is periodic with period $N$:

$$ g(u+N) = g(u)  \qquad \forall u \in \mathbb{R}.  $$

What is the closed-form expression for $g(u)$ in terms of $u$ and $N$?

For $N$ odd, we get the Dirichlet kernel:

$$ g(u) = \frac{\sin(\pi u)}{N \sin(\pi u/N)}. $$

I can then get that expression by an extension of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) and relating it to the continuous Fourier series:

$$ \hat{a}_k \triangleq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \, e^{-i 2 \pi nk/N}, $$

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} \hat{a}_k \, e^{+i 2 \pi nk/N}. $$

We know that both infinite sequences $a_n$ and $\hat{a}_k$ are periodic with period $N$.

Now, the continuous Fourier series for $f(x)$ is

$$ f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k \, e^{+i 2 \pi (k/N) x},  $$

and, because $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, we know we have conjugate symmetry

$$ c_{-k} = (c_k)^* \qquad \forall \ k \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

Being *"bandlimited"* means that

$$ c_k = 0 \qquad \forall \ |k| > \tfrac{N}{2}. $$

But when $N$ is even, what should $g(u)$ be?  Now there is potentially a non-zero component to the DFT value at what we EEs call the *"Nyquist frequency"*; namely  $\hat{a}_{N/2}$ exists and might not be zero.

The expression for $g(u)$ I get when $N$ is even is

$$ g(u) = \frac{\sin(\pi u)}{N \tan(\pi u/N)}. $$

But the question is: can it be, in the case that $N$ is even, that

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \, g(x-n)  + A \sin(\pi x),$$

where $A$ can be any real and finite number?

Do you math whiz-bangs know of a good way that I can say, for certain, that $A=0$?

---

So my most concise question is: for $N$ even and $a_n \in\mathbb{R}$ having period $N>0\in\mathbb{Z}$, namely

$$ a_{n+N}=a_n \qquad \forall \ n\in\mathbb{Z}, $$

is it true that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n \, \frac{\sin\big(\pi(x-n) \big)}{\pi(x-n)} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \frac{\sin\big(\pi (x-n)\big)}{N \tan\big(\pi (x-n)/N\big)} $$

??

---

Another way of looking at the question is this special case.  Can anyone prove that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n \, \frac{\sin\big(\pi(x-n) \big)}{\pi(x-n)} =  \cos(\pi x) $$

??

Comment: i realize that.  the Nyquist-Shannon sampling and reconstruction theorem is really built on the Poisson summation formula.  but i can't quite get a grip on whether i can prove that $A=0$ when $N$ is even.

Comment: Please write a *useful* title... one that will help others with the same or similar problem find the answers given here.

Comment: Bungo: since one of the sums is finite, you do not need absolute convergence to exchange the sums. Note, in the same way, that the convergence of these sums should be proved exactly like when proving that $\sum_{n \geq 1}{\operatorname{sinc}{n}}$ converges (and hold with the same meaning, aka $\sum_{m=-A}^B{\operatorname{sinc}(...)}$ has a limit when $A,B \rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: no, @JohnBentin , the period for $\cos(\pi x)$ also is $2$.

Comment: okay @DavidG.Stork , is the new title sufficiently useful?

Comment: Skip the distracting and useless references to "bonehead."  Do you see any other titles like that??

Comment: The periodicity is with respect to $n$, not $x$. Sure, $\cos\pi x$ has period $2$ with respect to $x$, but that isn't relevant. If the period for $n$ is $N=2$, with $a_n=(-1)^n$, then the RHS of the penultimate equation comprises two terms. However, their sum does indeed simplify to $\cos\pi x$, the same result as for $N=1$ and $a_0=1$, and the equation is correct. So I was wrong to question it—my apologies!

Comment: By saying

$$ a_{n+N}=a_n \qquad \forall \ n\in\mathbb{Z}. $$

$$ f(x+N) = f(x) \qquad \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}. $$

and 

$$ f(x) \Big|_{x = n} = a_n, $$

I thought I made it pretty clear that the periodicity applied to both the real, continuous function $f(x)$ and the real, discrete $a_n$ and that they have the same period, $N$.  The periodicity and period of the RHS is as relevant as the periodicity and period of the LHS if they are to both be equal in value at all of the integer arguments.

Comment: and @JohnBentin , do you have a decent proof that 

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n \, \frac{\sin\big(\pi(x-n) \big)}{\pi(x-n)} =  \cos(\pi x) $$

??

can you put that proof forth in an answer?

Comment: //" **If the period for $n$ is $N=2$, with $a_n=(−1)^n$, then the RHS of the penultimate equation comprises two terms.** "// ----- I had to look up the word *"penultimate"*.  So that is the proof.  I will check that out.  oh, wait.  That only proves the RHS is $\cos(\pi x)$, not the LHS.  I want to prove equality of the RHS to the LHS.

Answer (score 1):

The final equation can be written as$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2-x^2}=\frac1{2x^2}-\frac\pi{2x}\cot\pi x\quad(x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z),$$a proof of which can be found [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf).

Comment: By *"final equation"*, do you mean this: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n \, \frac{\sin\big(\pi(x-n) \big)}{\pi(x-n)} =  \cos(\pi x) \quad ?$$  Because I fail to see the intermediate steps and I fail to see how it gets us to to $\cos(\pi x)$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson  Yes. To get the equation in my answer from your (final) equation, use the fact that $(-1)^n\sin(\pi x-n\pi)=\sin\pi x$, separate the term for $n=0$, namely $(\sin\pi x)/\pi x$, pair up the remaining terms using the identity$$\frac1{x-n}+\frac1{x+n}=\frac{2x}{x^2-n^2},$$and divide through by $2x\sin\pi x$. To prove that the equation is true is not so elementary, and I don't know of an easier proof than the one I cited.

Comment: but even so, how do you get from $\frac1{2x^2}-\frac\pi{2x}\cot(\pi x)$ to $\cos(\pi x)$?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson After rearranging the equation, both sides of the equation change. Of course the expressions you give in your last comment do not equate.

Comment: Okay, just to be clear, you are saying this equality is false?

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n \,  \operatorname{sinc}(x-n)  =  \cos(\pi x) \qquad \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R} $$
where
$$ \operatorname{sinc}(u) \triangleq \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u}  & \text{if } u \ne 0, \\\;1 & \text{if } u = 0 \end{cases} $$

Is that the case?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson No, it's true. Just rearrange the equation a bit, as I explained in my first comment above, and you will get the equation in my answer. Your equation is true because it is equivalent to my equation, and the latter is proved in the linked paper.

Comment: grumble grumble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96000/discussion-between-john-bentin-and-robert-bristow-johnson).